# Python for in range()

Tags: python, function, python-3.x, spyder

I am doing a project using Python where I need to calculate the sum of squares the first part is:

> "Function squares(initial,terms) has two parameters: the initial
>   integer number in the series and the number of terms in the series. It
>   will use repetition to compute the sum of the series, and then return
>   the results. For example, if the first parameter is 2 and the second
>   parameter is 4, the function will return 54. Sum = 2^2 + 3^2 + 4^2 + 5^2 =
>   54"

In the hints for the problem it says to use:

```
for in range()
```

I am just having trouble with how to use this function in python and how to implement it.

Comment: You should make your question more readable than that. Dumping a single paragraph gives poor readability. Break it down in logical chunks.

Comment: how does Sum = 22 + 32 + 42 + 52 = 54 this works ? can u elaborate and add some code you have already done

Comment: i guess its 2 ** 2 + 3 ** 3 + 4 ** 4 + 5 ** 5 = 54 ??

Comment: Please take your time reading FAQ on [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and improve your question.

Comment: yes sorry I posted this late last night, it is the squares of those numbers, also that paragraph is included it because it explained the problem better than I could have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
sum([i ** 2 for i in range(initial, initial + terms)])
```

or

```
sum(map(lambda x: x ** 2, range(initial, initial + terms)))
```

both will work as the same way.

Comment: I used this approach perfectly for the answer, is it possible for me to pull out each value that is squared so that i can print the answer in the format as shown above?  ie "Sum = 2^2 + 3^2 + 4^2 + 5^2 = 54"

Comment: sorry for late reply. If you remove the sum then you can get the list of numbers. which you can use for the task.

Answer (score 0):

You can map the range to a squared form, then sum it up.

First, your range should look like this

```
l = range(initial,initial+terms)
```

Then, You can map this range with a function (I prefer using a lambda expression)

```
m = map(lambda x: x**2, l)
```

Finally, you can get the sum of this result.

```
sum(m)
```

Comment: Didn't saw your ans so one of my solution is similar to yours. Sorry didnt intend to.

Comment: @Harry It's a straightforward question, didn't expect much difference :)

Answer (score 0):

```
def squaresum(a,b):
    _sum = 0 # underline because sum is a function already
    for x in range(a,b):
        _sum += a**x
    return _sum
```